# How to read an excel file with extension csv in jupyter?

Tags: excel, csv, jupyter

I have an excel file- with .csv extension.
I want to read it in jupyter notebook.
my code is:

```
real_csv_data = 
pd.read_csv("/Users/xxx/Downloads/myfile.csv")
```

and I got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

myfile is an excel file, with .csv extension.
I tried the same with a .txt file- it was good.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I added a parameter to pd.read_csv()
now it looks like:

```
real_csv_data = 
pd.read_csv("/Users/xxx/Downloads/myfile.csv", encoding = "utf-16")
```

and now it works fine.
also if someone interested- you can also add 
`sep = '/t'`
 for example, to get the data in a nice table.